# AngularJS and Onsen ui not working on Windows Phone 8

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8, onsen-ui

I am developing a cordova project with angularjs and onsenui.
But angularjs is not working on windows phone 8.1 .
For Angularjs add winstore-jscompat.js . Then Angularjs working.
But onsen not working.

```
@font-face encountered unknown error.
Error: fail to get ".page__content" element.
```

Please help me with this.